# Sharing Exchange Server email messages... not in a PST, and not in Public Folders

Tags: exchange-2010, public-folders, migration

We are trying to reduce the amount of messages in our Public Folder databases.  Many users use Public folders to share "team-related" information in a central place.

The messages in this folder are from many different users, and so they aren't available in a [typical archive](http://www.proofpoint.com/products/archive/index.php).

What solutions support the online sharing of email messages among a variety of Exchange connected users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create a [Shared Mailbox](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb201680.aspx), and have the users add it to their outlook profile.

My suggestion however is this:

Install [SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee263910) and configure incoming e-mail.

This way, you can enable the users to send their "team-related" information directly from Outlook and have it published in a document library on a sharepoint site which they all had access to.

Technet article on [Configuring Incoming Email in SharePoint Foundation 2010](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287879.aspx)

Pretty straight-forward guide to setting it up and [enabling incoming email on a document library](http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/10/20/how-to-setup-mail-enabled-document-libraries-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1/)

Comment: Is it feasible to move a public folder hierarchy to sharepoint in some way?  Suppose messages are grouped by Customer... is each folder a document library?  I'm dealing with historic mail.. so enabling incoming mail doesn't completely solve my issue.

Comment: Through any of a number of 3rd party migration tools available, it IS indeed feasible. Have a look at http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2008/03/31/3405234.aspx